# PHP to Javascript Variable via AJAX/XML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

First to make it clear. I want to do this without using jQuery, in other words, yes I want to re-invent the wheel to understand how the wheel works. To my understanding this is possible via AJAX, but the net seems to only provide jQuery solutions to the problem. My goal is to generate an html document using javascript, but in turn after the page has loaded output only the non-script stub of the documents outerHTML via javascript to a new .php file which contains only the specified text.

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    include 'devScript.php';

    $div = new Div();
    $div->setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
?>
```

**devScript.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var srcScript;
    var devScript;
    var stubScript;

    (function() {

        document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('body'));

        srcScript = document.head.innerHTML;



    }());


    window.onload = function() {



        devScript = document.head.innerHTML.toString().replace(srcScript, '');
        document.documentElement.removeChild(document.documentElement.lastChild);

        stubScript = document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString().replace(srcScript, '').replace(devScript, '');

        alert("Full Script!");
        alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
        alert('Stub Script');
        alert(stubScript);

<?php
/*
  $file = fopen("iHateWritingHtmlTags.php", 'w');
  fwrite($file, stubScript);

  This DOES NOT WORK!!!!
 */
?>


    }

    function Div() {

        Div.STATIC = 'static';
        Div.ABSOLUTE = 'absolute';
        Div.RELATIVE = 'relative';
        Div.FIXED = 'fixed';
        Div.SOLID = 'solid';
        Div.DOTTED = 'dotted';
        Div.LEFT = 0;
        Div.CENTER = 1;
        Div.RIGHT = 2;
        Div.TOP = 0;
        Div.MIDDLE = 1;
        Div.BOTTOM = 2;

        var ELEMENT;
        var CSS;

        var horizontalAlign;
        var verticalAlign;

        var colorQueue;



        (function() {

            this.div = document.createElement('div');

            ELEMENT = this.div;
            CSS = this.div.style;

            CSS.border = '1px solid black';



            document.body.appendChild(this.div);



        }());

        this.setPosition = function(postype) {

            if (!horizontalAlign && !verticalAlign) {

                CSS.position = postype;

            }


        }

        this.setBounds = function(x, y, width, height) {

            CSS.left = x + 'px';
            CSS.top = y + 'px';
            CSS.width = width + 'px';
            CSS.height = height + 'px';

        }

        this.setColorQueue = function(r, g, b) {

            colorQueue = 'rgb(' + new Array(r, g, b) + ')';
            alert(colorQueue);

        }

        this.horizontalAlign = function(horiz) {

            var freeSpaceX = ((window.innerWidth - ELEMENT.offsetWidth) / 2);
            var defPadding = '8px';
            var defPaddingCenter;
            var defPaddingRight;
            var defPaddingLeft;

            horizontalAlign = true;

            this.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

            if (CSS.position == 'relative' || CSS.position == 'absolute') {

                CSS.position = 'absolute';
                defPaddingCenter = 12;
                defPaddingRight = 4;
                defPaddingLeft = 8;



            } else if (CSS.position == 'fixed') {

                defPaddingCenter = 4;
                defPaddingRight = 4;
                defPaddingLeft = 8;

            }

            if (horiz == 0) {

                if (!verticalAlign) {
                    CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
                }
                CSS.marginLeft = defPaddingLeft + 'px';

            } else if (horiz == 1) {

                if (!verticalAlign) {
                    CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
                }
                CSS.marginLeft = freeSpaceX - defPaddingCenter + 'px';

            } else if (horiz == 2) {

                if (!verticalAlign) {
                    CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
                }
                CSS.marginLeft = (freeSpaceX - defPaddingRight) * 2 + 'px';

            }

        }

    }


</script>
<?php

class Div {

    public $obj_id;

    function __construct() {

        $this->obj_id = "_" . uniqid(rand());

        echo '<script>',
        'var ' . $this->obj_id . ' = new Div();',
        '</script>';
    }

    function setPosition() {

        echo '<script>',
        $this->obj_id . '.setPosition();',
        '</script>';
    }

    function setBounds($x, $y, $width, $height) {


        $parse_string = $x . ',' . $y . ',' . $width . ',' . $height;


        echo '<script>',
        $this->obj_id . '.setBounds(' . $parse_string . ');',
        '</script>';
    }

    function setColorQueue() {

        echo '<script>',
        $this->obj_id . '.setColorQueue();',
        '</script>';
    }

    function horizontalAlign() {

        echo '<script>',
        $this->obj_id . '.horizontalAlign();',
        '</script>';
    }

}
?>
```

**NOTE:** The Root of the problem is in index.php. Feel free to test these two out on firefox because the alert box has a scroll bar. :)

**OUTPUT:**
iHateWritingHtmlTags.php only contains "stubScript" as its text not the actual javascript variable stubScript?!?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @SLaks Do you happen to have cross-browser a code implementation of this? I want to skip the trial by error steps. :)

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is cross browser, if you want something that handles all browsers (including old versions of IE, etc.) use jQuery or some other framework that handles this abstraction for you.

Comment: The root of your problem appears to be you're loading in JS and trying to execute it on the server side using PHP. JS is client side and PHP is server side, so the JS isn't going to have rendered until after PHP is done, you also just can't call straight up JS (your call to new Div(), which is a JS function) through PHP.

Comment: @Busches I know I was attempting to experiment with php echos to javascript functions to see if I could some how get this to work through that, but it didn't. I just never changed back to just calling javascript directly. Is there anyway to access an empty php variable and set it equal to an already existing javascript variable?

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder, you are confused about client- and server-side operations.

Comment: @DwayneTowell So is this just impossible? I thought you could always just reaccess variables used on the server so why can't, while javascript is executing, javascript define an empty $php variable?

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder you can have PHP spit out JS, because JS is only parsed after it's sent to the browser and PHP is done. If you want to sent something from JS to PHP, then you need to use AJAX.

Comment: @Busches Can you provide an example without using jQuery please. ;) sorry i am asking this, but I am really only trying to understand javascript purely. Particularly, because I have researched jQuery and it does not perform well with graphics intensive animations on the web.

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder see the 2nd and 3rd comments and how not to use jQuery. Also, using jQuery (or alternative library) for AJAX has nothing to with graphics intensive animations.

Comment: @Busches I know that I mean the use of jQuery period has some limitations for performing animations using jQuery.animate();. According to this article anyway http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Let "variable" be the name of the Javascript variable

```
<form action="." method="get">

<input type='hidden' name='Javascript_Variable' value='<script>document.write(variable);</script>'>

</form>
```

Now, in PHP:

```
<?php

 $phpVariable = $_GET['Javascript_Variable'];

?>
```

Comment: This is good for storing a php variable into javascript, but i need vice-versa.

Comment: Then you can reserve the process by creating a hidden input type with a form around it whose value is that of the javascript variable and then taking the PHP variable by taking the value of $_GET['name of hidden input']

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer with what you have suggested please.

Comment: Yes, I made the changes to the above example.

Comment: I am having a hard time create the input via javascript.

Comment: Is it name or id for the input tag?

Comment: My php is outputing nothing.